# Laravel Method filter does not exist when updating 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am getting this error while updating Laravel 5.1 to 5.2.

BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method filter does not exist

any help ?

here is stack trace

BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method filter does not exist.

```
in Macroable.php line 74
at Router->__call('filter', array('auth', object(Closure))) in Facade.php line 219
at Router->filter('auth', object(Closure)) in Facade.php line 219
at Facade::__callStatic('filter', array('auth', object(Closure))) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 56
at Route::filter('auth', object(Closure)) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 56
at RouteServiceProvider->boot(object(Router))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot'), array(object(Router))) in Container.php line 507
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot')) in Application.php line 757
at Application->bootProvider(object(RouteServiceProvider)) in Application.php line 740
at Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(object(RouteServiceProvider), '18')
at array_walk(array(object(EventServiceProvider), object(RoutingServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(CookieServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider), object(EncryptionServiceProvider), object(FilesystemServiceProvider), object(FoundationServiceProvider), object(PaginationServiceProvider), object(SessionServiceProvider), object(ViewServiceProvider), object(LaravelPushNotificationServiceProvider), object(ImageServiceProvider), object(BarcodeServiceProvider), object(CloudderServiceProvider), object(AppServiceProvider), object(ConfigServiceProvider), object(EventServiceProvider), object(RouteServiceProvider)), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 741
at Application->boot() in BootProviders.php line 17
at BootProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 232
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 127
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are getting this.

Comment: I am running index file of my view. i do not use filter in routes.php file

Comment: Could you please give us the stack trace?

Comment: @AdreAstrian I have edited my question and added stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace I got this `Route::filter('auth', object(Closure)) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 56`? So check your `RouteServiceProvider.php` file in line number `56`. You have a `filter` call. Update it with the `v5.2` code. That should fix your issue.

Comment: I was using BeforFilter function in my controller constructor... searching for replacement of that in v5.2.